# Do assemblies require physical presence on disk?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, appdomain

I (like probably so many before me) tried to use the deprecated `Assembly.Load(Byte[])` method to load an assembly into an application domain where said assembly data is transmitted over the network and therefore has technically no physical presence. I think I've been through just about every nook and cranny to try to get this to work, but I'm pretty convinced this is impossible (at least perhaps using my current methods).

I guess my question is, is it true that in order to load an assembly, it must be located in the `CodeBase`/`GAC` of the application? If so, why is that?

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Comment: Still seems to search the disk for an actual copy of the assembly. Which is odd - what's the point of having a `Byte[]` override, if it still wants you to have the file on disk?

Comment: It's deprecated? Can't seem to find anything stating that...

Comment: Gah, I've been fighting with this for so long. And now magically it seems to be working.

Comment: @Chris. So this is odd, if you type in `Assembly.Load` intellisense says that the method is deprecated. However, if you type `Assembly.Load(...` it's undeprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true.  You *can* load an assembly from a byte array; that array can come from anywhere.  As an example, I've previously worked with a system that loaded plugins from assemblies that were stored as a binary field in a database.

(Perhaps you should ask another question and include the issue you've faced, so that you can get this working :-))

Comment: Hmm. I'll have to experiment more then.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. You only need actual byte [] data of you .dll file, after you call Load method it loads in CLR everything goes OK.